# Subplot Not Aligning

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to make a subplot but the first plot is not showing its also not aligning by the side.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ondCR.jpg)
this is my code below:

```
# Plot of Total Number of Male and Female Athletes in each Year 

plt.figure(figsize=[20, 5])
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
summer_gender_participants.plot(kind='bar', x='Year', y=['Male','Female'], edgecolor='Black')
plt.title("Summer Participant By Gender Count")
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Number by Gender')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
winter_gender_participants.plot(kind='line', x='Year', y=['Male','Female'])
plt.title("Winter Participant By Gender Count")
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Number by Gender')
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to change to the object oriented programing style and try to get the data directly in a numpy array or a list, to have more control over your plot.

Also you need to note that these two lines of code

```
summer_gender_participants.plot(kind='bar', x='Year', y=['Male','Female'], edgecolor='Black')
```

and the line

```
winter_gender_participants.plot(kind='line', x='Year', y=['Male','Female'])
```

have nothing to do with the plot you create later, that's the reason why the plot is empty, because have no data input

so, you can do something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# the data is an numpy array or a list
summer_gender_year = the_summer_year_data
summer_male = summer_male_data
summer_female = summer_female_data


winter_gender_year = the_winter_year_data
winter_male = winter_male_data
winter_female = winter_female_data


# you create the fig object
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)


# ax1 is the first plot
ax1.plot(summer_gender_year, summer_male)
ax1.plot(summer_gender_year, summer_female)
ax1.set_title("Summer Participant By Gender Count")
ax1.set_xlabel('Year')
ax1.set_ylabel('Number by Gender')

# ax2 is the first plot
ax2.plot(winter_gender_year, winter_male)
ax2.plot(winter_gender_year, winter_female)
ax2.set_title("Winter Participant By Gender Count")
ax2.set_xlabel('Year')
ax2.set_ylabel('Number by Gender')
```

and you can try to get the data from `summer_gender_participants` and `winter_gender_participants`, you just need to inspect the api behind those objects